# Is \renewcommand{\fi} possible?

Tags: macros

I am writing my own command and i would like to define for each letter :

`\newcommand{\fletter}{\mathfrak{letter}}`

but i can't do it for the letter i even with `\renewcommand`.

Is it possible to define that command for the letter i?

Comment: Hi and welcome, I am a lazy guy, others say efficient, as well. If you want to save typing time, get an editor which deals with stuff like that. Even tough LaTeX is made of/for macros, there are limits. Your editors will be greatful as well, if you avoid such shortcuts.

Comment: Perhaps using a capital "F" might improve your chances, but even there I am not sure.

Answer (score 12):

There are some cases where `\renewcommand` can be safely used; the main one is when we want to modify the behavior of a command we know about: the classical

```
\let\latexsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  ...<something to do before a section title>...
  \latexsection
}
```

is a frequently used trick.

Another case is something like

```
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
```

so we are sure that even if we type `\phi` the “open” shape will be used.

Other cases may include clobbering a command name which we know about and that we are *absolutely sure* we won't use in our document. Say that a package we load provides a command `\foo` that's only used at the top level and that we don't need; however, this is not really recommended.

A colleague once called me asking why he was not able to typeset the name of his coauthor in a paper, because LaTeX complained with weird error messages. The problem was that the coauthor was Turkish and his name contained `Ş`.

If one uses an encoding supporting `Ş`, what TeX sees is `\c{S}`, just as if this longer combination is typed. Well, it turned out that my colleague had

```
\renewcommand{\c}{\gamma}
```

in his preamble. (Actually it was `\def\c{\gamma}` which is even much worse, but the effect is the same.)

*Never ever* clobber accent commands like `\c`: you can't know whether they will be used for your bibliography, for instance.

***Never ever*** use `\renewcommand` on a command which you don't precisely know about; be suspicious when `\renewcommand` appears in code obtained from not fully trusted sources.<sup>1</sup>. Ask some expert in case of doubt or if you start getting weird error messages from LaTeX.

***NEVER EVER*** use `\renewcommand` on commands that are not listed in the index of the LaTeX manual or in the [“Comprehensive List of LaTeX Symbols”](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), unless you know ***PRECISELY*** what you're doing.

Note that the command `\fi` is neither in index of the manual nor in the list of symbols.

> Redefining commands such as `\if`, `\fi`, `\box` will make processing your document into a nightmare of mysterious errors, without getting any sensible output. It's similar to redefining `\begin` or `\end`, but ***much worse***.

Experts can, in some cases, find a workaround to a tough problem by *locally* redefining a primitive so that it does a different job than it's normally expected to, but such tricks are very dangerous and can blow up very easily if not done in a controlled environment.

<sub><sup>1</sup>I sometimes consider myself a trusted source. `;-)`</sub>

Comment: You know egreg is being serious when there's a text in all caps, bold and italics. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

It's possible, in the sense you can make the definition if you use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` but it would break almost all latex usage, so I don't recommend it.

Even this fails

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\fi}{\mathfrak{i}}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Latex refuses to compile if is use \renewcommand instead of \newcommand.

Comment: @Gomme Sure, because -- as David said -- you are breaking thousands of commands which use \fi as the end of a \if-clause.

Comment: @Gomme I bet LaTeX is giving you a reason?

Comment: @Gomme No. latex never refuses. It makes the definition as specified, but then every command that makes any kind of test fails as you have redefined `\fi` which is tex's end-if command.

Comment: @Johannes_B the error you get from the above is `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` which isn't necessarily the most obvious error message in that context:-)

Comment: it would break plain usage too.  `\fi` is a primitive, and it's *never* a good idea to redefine one of those.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of clobbering `\fi`, which really would be a bad idea, define a command `\f` (which is available for being defined) as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand\f[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\begin{document}

$\f i$

\end{document}
```

Then you get your math frak as desired.

The nice thing about using `\newcommand`, as opposed to `\def` or just letting `\let\f\mathfrak`, is that `\newcommand` will warn you if the command name has already been taken.   Of course you could also always do something like

```
\newcommand\f{}
\let\f\mathfrak
```

and then you get the warning before clobbering something that you may need for your document to compile as expected.

Comment: `\let\f\mathfrak` could even be more economical (if you are sure `\f` is not already defined)

Comment: @Bordaigorl True.